# Why session does not be duplicated in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I am learning session and cookie in rails and I am confusing about session storing in rails.
When a user (named U1) login into a rails sever (named A), A will create a session and store it somewhere:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

As above command, I will be thinking that session of user U1 will be stored into a **session** array and has index **user_id**.
But when a other user (named U2) login into server A, the above command also be called and also has index is **user_id**. So why index **user_id** of U1 is not replaced of **user_id** of U2 (because both users U1 and U2 use shared **session** array)

Comment: If you are using different browser instance(window), the cookies will not shared to each other, so your session key is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How Works:**

1.When you call `session[:current_user_id] = 1` in your app, and a session doesn’t already exist:

2.Rails will create a new record in your sessions table with a random session ID (say, `09497d46978bf6f32265fefb5cc52264`).

3.It’ll store `{current_user_id: 1} (Base64-encoded)` in the data attribute of that record.

4.And it’ll return the generated `session ID, 09497d46978bf6f32265fefb5cc52264`, to the browser using Set-Cookie.

**The next time you request a page,**

1.The browser sends that same cookie to your app, using the Cookie: header.

like this:

```
Cookie: _my_app_session=09497d46978bf6f32265fefb5cc52264;
path=/; HttpOnly
```

2.When you call `session[:current_user_id]`:

3.Your app grabs the session ID out of your cookie, and finds its record in the sessions table.

4.Then, it returns current_user_id out of the data attribute of that record.

Comment: I do not use sessions with ActiveRecord above, I am learning rails from rails tutorial book.

Comment: @Hung Okay, this is only for your knowledge.

Comment: @Hung if you are satisfied with my ans then make it correct

Comment: it is not satisfied me but it provided me the additional knowledge.

Comment: @Hung   Can you please tell me why my answer is not vote up or not corrected, I believe that my answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate `session` created for each user. This is done by the server and the server keeps track of sessions per user.

Comment: "per user" here mean "per browser" or "per IP address"? If I open 2 window browsers then it can be assumed 2 users?